# jQuery UI slider does not work for all decimal values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have made a slider using jQuery UI slider for some variables from a json. This is my code

```
$( "#slider_" + hashmap[this.value].name).slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: hashmap[this.value].prop[0],
                    max: hashmap[this.value].prop[1],
                    values: [ hashmap[this.value].prop[0], hashmap[this.value].prop[1]],
                    slide: function( event, ui ) { 
                      tooltipmin.text(ui.values[0]);
                      tooltipmax.text(ui.values[1]);
                    },
                    change: function(event,ui){
                      var range_value = $(this).slider('values')
                      var name = $(this).attr('id').substring($(this).attr('id').indexOf("_")+1)
                      var type = 'quant';
                      tooltipmin.text(ui.values[0]);
                      tooltipmax.text(ui.values[1]);
                      filterValues(name, range_value, type)
                    }
```

JSON

```
{
        "type": "quant",
        "name": "dmin",
        "prop": [
            0.0009815,
            1.58
        ]
    },
{
        "type": "quant",
        "name": "horizontalError",
        "prop": [
            0.1,
            10.6
        ]
    },
 {
        "type": "quant",
        "name": "magError",
        "prop": [
            0.0,
            1.34
        ]
    },
{
        "type": "quant",
        "name": "rms",
        "prop": [
            0.0,
            0.87
        ]
    },
```

The code works fine for most of the variables(horizontal error). But weirdly it does not work for other variables whose name is "rms","dmin" and "magError". For these three variables, the slider does not work at all. The handles are frozen at the min and max position. Even the console does not give any error. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your `step` value? I don't see it defined. The default is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to set your `min`, `max`, and `step` properly. In most cases, the min will be `0` and the max and step will be somewhat variable. You may consider using `Math.ceil()` like so:

```js
var hashmap = [{
    "type": "quant",
    "name": "dmin",
    "prop": [
      0.0009815,
      1.58
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "quant",
    "name": "horizontalError",
    "prop": [
      0.1,
      10.6
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "quant",
    "name": "magError",
    "prop": [
      0.0,
      1.34
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "quant",
    "name": "rms",
    "prop": [
      0.0,
      0.87
    ]
  }
];

$(function() {
  $(".slide").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    step: .00001,
    create: function(e, ui) {
      var slide = $(this);
      var type = "quant";
      var name = slide.attr("name");
      var props = hashmap[slide.data("id")].prop;
      slide.slider("option", {
        min: 0,
        max: Math.ceil(props[1]),
        values: props
      });
      slide.next("p").html("Values: <span>[" + props.join(", ") + "]</span>; Min: 0, Max: " + Math.ceil(props[1]));
    },
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      var slide = $(this);
      slide.next("p").find("span").html("[" + ui.values.join(", ") + "]")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider-1" class="slide" data-id="0" name="dmin"></div>
<p>Values:</p>

<div id="slider-2" class="slide" data-id="1" name="horizontalError"></div>
<p>Values:</p>

<div id="slider-3" class="slide" data-id="2" name="magError"></div>
<p>Values:</p>

<div id="slider-4" class="slide" data-id="3" name="rms"></div>
<p>Values:</p>
```

If you can, I would adjust your JSON data to include more details for the sliders. Something like:

```
{
  "type": "quant",
  "name": "dmin",
  "props": {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 5,
    "step": .00001
    "values": [
      0.00098,
      1.58
    ]
  }
};
```